# Very strange issue of makefile, No such file or directory

Tags: linux, makefile, centos

I came across a very strange issue of makefile, here it is:
System: Linux CentOS 6
In the beginning, the name of makefile is “makefile”, its sample contents:

```
OPTFLAGS = -Wall -g -O
CXX = g++ 
INC = -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64    
CXXFLAGS = $(OPTFLAGS) $(INC)

SOURCES = file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

EXECUTABLE = mybin

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $(LIBS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

file1.o : file1.cpp
file2.o : file2.cpp
file3.o : file3.cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE) *.o core*
```

I got following err after I ran “make”:
 g++: file3.o: No such file or directory

I have a workaround to add a dummy file after file3:

```
dummy.o : dummy.cpp
```

This way I could build successfully.

And I know that I can delete all these lines:

```
file1.o : file1.cpp
file2.o : file2.cpp
file3.o : file3.cpp
```

let make to build using default settings, I could build successfully this way.

I also tried to just rename “makefile” to “Makefile”, and with following lines without dummy line:

```
file1.o : file1.cpp
file2.o : file2.cpp
file3.o : file3.cpp
```

To my surprise, I could build successfully this way.

Could anyone explain why I got error of “No such file or directory” for the last file3 in the beginning?

Following is the error output:

```
g++ -g -Wall -O -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include     -c -o file1.o file1.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -O -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include     -c -o file2.o file2.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -O -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include   -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64 -lsybdb    file1.o file2.o file3.o -o mybin
g++: file3.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [mybin] Error 1
```

Following is the output after I added dummy line:

```
g++  -Wall -g -O -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include     -c -o file1.o file1.cpp
g++  -Wall -g -O -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include     -c -o file2.o file2.cpp
g++  -Wall -g -O -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include     -c -o file3.o file3.cpp
g++  -Wall -g -O -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include   -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib64 -lsybdb    file1.o file2.o file3.o -o mybin
```

I tried to rename "makefile" to "Makefile" again, and it doesn't work this time.

Comment: Can you show us the *exact* output from running `make` when it fails?

Comment: @wallyk No, if that was the problem you would see something like `make: *** No rule to make target \`file3.o'. Stop.` That error means `g++` can't find `file3.o` which sounds like it failed to get created correctly somehow.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ufffff!! Found your problem.

When you wrote

```
file1.o : file1.cpp
file2.o : file2.cpp
file3.o : file3.cpp
```

in your `makefile` a deamon came and introduced a TAB after the line `file3.o : file3.cpp` so make instead of taking implicit rule thought you are specifying explicit rule. For `file1.o` and `file2.o` it used implicit rule but for `file3.o` it assumed your are specifying explicit rule because of that TAB, but you had given it a blank TAB so `file3.o` was never built.

Now when you added `dummy.o:dummy.cpp` the TAB moved below that line so `file3.o` was compiled. When you were experimenting around you deleted that TAB that's why renaming `makefile` to `Makefile` seemed to work.

Just FYI: there is no difference between `Makefile` or `makefile` both are treated equally by make, except when both `Makefile` and `makefile` files are there in same folder and you give make then `makefile` is executed instead of `Makefile`

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. You are so conscientious, thanks a lot!